# Output of an algorithm in QGIS Graphic Modeler

Tags: qgis, select-by-attribute, select-by-location, model

I use two Processing tools in a graphic Model in QGIS:

1-Select by Location

2-Select by Attribute

The problem is that I can't get the output of the selection by location so that I can't use it as input for other algorithms.

[image]

Comment: I believe you are looking for the 'Extract selected features' algorithm after your select algorithms. Use this algorithm after after your selection and then use this as your input into the next tree in the model.

Comment: I found the 'Extract by location' and 'Extract by attribut' algorithms. so there is no need to select then extract selected features . well it is the same thing with less algorithms. thanx for your help, can you add as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Select by Location** tool doesn't give any output. It just selects features. If you want to process on selected features you have to add "Extract selected features" tool and set "Select by Location" as **parent algorithm** of "Extract selected features" tool. Then you can use the output as input for other algorithms.

[image]